# Adding a SQL alias statement to an SQL SELECT * FROM command in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, command-line, alias

I am currently pulling an SQL table into a data grid view in VB.net. People will be reading this table and the column names have no spaces and are short handed for coding purposes. I was wondering if/how I can include a list of SQL Alias commands to change these column names into something more legible and ergonomic instead of what I used in the code.

```
Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
    Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM TPM.dbo.tblFCTPM; Select Name as Associate from TPM.dbo.tblFCTPM", conn1)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = comm1
        da.Fill(dt)
        'select customerName as customer, contactname as contact person
        'from cusomters;
    End Using

    conn1.Close()
End Using

DGVPM.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: `DGVPM.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Your Column Title"`

Comment: Got it, Your the man!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases allow you to escape names with double quotes (remember: strings in SQL are delimited by single quotes):

```
SELECT SomeName AS "Some Name" FROM myTbl
```

SQL-Server AND JetEngine (Access) allow brackets:

```
SELECT SomeName AS [Some Name] FROM myTbl
```

But you can also change the column headers programmatically:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "First Column";
```

Or by column name:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["SomeName"].HeaderText = "Some Name";
```